# Execute XSJS program in SAP HANA Neo using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hana, xsjs

Is there a way to run or debug an XSJS program in SAP HANA (Neo) using Eclipse Neon Release 4.6.3?

I have installed SAP plug-in in Eclipse and connected to the database in System view. However, I do not know how to execute the XSJS file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only way is to create new XS project in Eclipse and deploy it, there is no way to execute standalone `xsjs` files.

Provided you [installed](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools) SAP Hana Tools on your Eclipse environment you should create XS project [according to standard procedure](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/3762b229a4074fc59ac6a9ee7404f8c9.html#loio93cfb85816144ec292bf115b6c8bb190) and then import your file into project by [standard Eclipse toolset](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-55.htm).

Use Neon repository for installation SAP Hana Tools

https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/neon/

Comment: As you told me, I was able to create a new XS Project and run xsjs.
I'm investigating a way to run an existing xsjs program.
Thank you for the information.

Comment: Suncatcher is right: xsjs files are executed on the server only. More specifically by the XSEngine service that is part of the HANA server. It’s not possible to run those files locally.